# What happens when I leave Taiwan with a used visa?

Tags: visas, taiwan

I came to Taiwan in July with a regular entry visa. I was going to work. My employer took my passport, but the job didn't work out and I never received a work visa. I got my passport back with a 90 Day Single Entry visitor's visa issued in August, and with an entry stamp for September.It is also stamped "used". I now want to leave Taiwan. It should be okay because of it has been less than 90 days since that entry date, but does the stamp marked "used" cause problems?

Comment: You have a Single Entry visa, and you've entered once. You've used your visa, so why should the 'Used' stamp be an issue?